# how switch register globals off

Tags: php

my web hosting has the register globals on and I need to turn it off, when using a .htaccess with the following code in the root directory

```
php_flag register_globals off
```

I get the following error

```
Internal Server Error, this is an error with your script, check your error log for more  information.
```

any ideas please.

Comment: It says "check your error log for more  information.". And? Can you paste it here as well?

Comment: where can I find the error log?

Comment: in the .error file I get this

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
    <title>404 Not Found</title>
    </head><body>
    <h1>Not Found</h1>
    <p>The requested URL was not found on this server.
</body></html>

Answer (score 3):

most likely your host is not allowing that setting in .htaccess files. If you have a php file that is always included you can turn it off there

```
ini_set('register_globals', false);
```

Comment: In addendum to this, you could put this code in a PHP file and then auto-prepend this to each file:

    php_value auto_prepend_file "doregisterglobals.php"

Answer (score 1):

If worse comes to worse and you can not disable it, try this psuedo code

- Loop through all superglobals
- If $var = $_SUPERGLOB[$var] then `unset()`

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the .htaccess file and placing a php.ini file in its place with register_globals = Off in it.

The 500 server error from a .htaccess file points to php being run as a CGI rather than an Apache Module

Comment: this doesn't seem to turn off the register globals either, is there any other ways, thanks